# Pre Install App or pre burn build is possible through OEM

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Can you please share any link or tutorial how we will make pre-install app or pre-burn build through OEM?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that. Pre-installed apps are authorized by Microsoft to a specific Manufacturer on a ROM.

If you want to know if an app is pre-installed or not you can use [DeviceExtendedProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties(v=vs.105).aspx) class, then in your code you can use IsApplicationPreInstalled property.

Comment: Hi Christian- By the help of OEM we can make pre burn build, which build we have to submit windows phone store and vendor will use that build for pre install app..... :)